# How to install a sdk different from the one that comes with Xcode by default?

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I just downloaded Xcode 4.1 that comes with 4.3.2 sdk.

I have built a little app and what to test it against 3.X.X and 4.2. Is there any possibility of downloading the sdk's separately and install them? I mean without Xcode 3.X, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select which versions of the iOS your app is suitable for. Appropriate versions of the simulator will appear.

You can set it in Xcode -> Targets -> Build Settings -> Deployment -> iOS Deployment Settings
Set that to iOS 3.0 and launch appropriate simulator.